# Backing up Web Server Locally

Tags: server, linux, backups

As an added backup, I'd love to have an external hard drive sitting here with my Mac that backs up our web server. Is there any way to have a total backup initially done of the entire web server, with it then doing any changed documents after that?

Server is running linux (hosted by Media Temple, dv 4.0 / Plesk 10.x)
Local machine is a Mac running OS X Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` or `rdiff-backup` are good tools for doing this. rsync is available with MacOS X I believe. I found a good tutorial on how to do use them with Plesk here: http://vmblog.com/archive/2006/12/02/2378.aspx

Quick examples:

```
rsync -aze ssh root@remoteserver:/var/lib/mysql /backup/mysql
rdiff-backup user@hostname.net::/remote-dir local-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You've tried tar? tar is good!
Well, rsync is good too. For the time being, let me tell you about tar.

```
tar zvcf - $PWD | ssh -i keyfile.pem username@ip-address "dd of=/home/tarfile"
```

I am assuming you can build the trust (exchange of ky pairs) for logging in.
Using **v** flag is a good thing.